# Eclipse: some keyboard's key suddenly stop working

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I feel **the need** to understand **why**, while I'm working in eclipse, some keys stop working, especially *backspace* and *del* keys.

I have searched on the net and found that it is recognized as a bug: I often read that the problem is related to other applications.

So the best advice is to restart Eckipse. (???)

Someone should explain to the Eclipse's developers that it cannot stop working (or working bad) if some other application stops working or crashes.

**ps.** Now I'm working in Ubuntu, but I see that the problem is platform-independent.

Comment: What is a "canc" key?

Comment: @JimGarrison Edited.. however I think it was exaggerated the suggestion to close the question and the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you use many keyboard layouts, you may have accidentally changed them by pressing `alt+shift`. If that's the case, pressing it again will restore it to the normal layout.